# UICollectionView.setContentOffset(...) causing NSRangeException

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've got a `UICollectionView` representing a calendar, with 13 months of data generated on load and a section for each month. There's a button in the UI to toggle between the current year and the next year, but when scrolling from the end of the collection back to the start of the current year the app crashes with the following error.

`'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 9223372036854775806 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'`

This is the method causing the error.

```
public func scrollTo(year: Int) {
    if let month = months.firstIndex(where: { $0.components.year == year }),
        let attributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: month)){
        let y = attributes.frame.origin.y - collectionView.contentInset.top

        // This is the line causing the error
        collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), animated: true)
    }
}
```

I've tried printing out my calculated `y` value, but it's been `0` every time it crashes.

It might be worth noting that the index mentioned in the exception is equal to `Int.max - 1`, although seeing as `y` is a `CGFloat` I'm not sure how this is relevant.

Comment: Your error does not look about scrolling... It's about accessing data at an index that does not exist.... I would check itemForIndex

Comment: @MCMatan It's definitely not that method, it's directly using the `section` and `item` properties of the index path, lining up with the values given in `numberOfSections` and `numberOfItemsInSection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that the animation was causing the crash, but changing `animated` to `false` in the call to `setContentOffset(...)` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this built in UICollectionView instance method
`scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` with your indexpath you calculated?

> Scrolls the collection view contents until the specified item is visible.
>   [from apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618046-scrolltoitem)

Comment: If I replace the call to `setContentOffset` with `collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: month), at: .top, animated: true)` then it still crashes with the same error for some reason

Comment: did you check if the indexpath exists in the collectionview?

Comment: Yes, the path is definitely valid